ESP32 INTEGRATED WITH BARCODE SCANNER AND ANDROID APP, removing items from recyclerview and firebase realtime
I want to remove an item from RecyclerView and Firebase when i click the remove button. my code is here MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: ItemAdapter
    private lateinit var items: MutableList<ProductData>
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.item_main)

        // Initialize RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        items = mutableListOf()
        adapter = ItemAdapter(items, this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        hideSystemUI()

        // Initialize Firebase database reference
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scannedItems")

        // Fetch product data from Firebase
        fetchScannedItems()


        // Set listener for system UI visibility changes
        window.decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
            if ((visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                hideSystemUI()
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to fetch product data from Firebase
    // MainActivity.kt
    private fun fetchScannedItems() {
        database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                items.clear()  // Clear list to avoid duplicates
                for (productSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val product = productSnapshot.getValue(ProductData::class.java)
                    product?.let { items.add(it) }  // Add product to list if not null
                }
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Fetched items: $items")
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  // Update RecyclerView
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("MainActivity", "loadPost:onCancelled", error.toException())
            }
        })
    }


    // Listen for changes in scanned items in Firebase and update RecyclerView


    // Hide the system UI (e.g., status bar and navigation bar)
    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        val decorView = window.decorView
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                )
    }

    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI()
        }
    }


}


my ItemAdapter.kt

class ItemAdapter(private var items: MutableList<ProductData>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {



    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val itemNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_itemName)
        val itemPriceTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_Price)
        val qtyTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_qty)
        val deleteButton: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = items[position]  // Corrected variable name to 'product' to align with usage
        holder.itemNameTextView.text = product.productName
        holder.itemPriceTextView.text = "₱${product.productPrice}"
        holder.qtyTextView.text = "Qty: ${product.qty}"

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener{
            deleteItem(position)
        }
    }



    private fun deleteItem(position: Int) {
        // Handle case if the item is already removed or invalid position
        if (position < 0 || position >= items.size) {
            return
        }

        val product = items[position]
        val productBarcode = product.productBarcode

        // Firebase reference
        val itemRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scannedItems").child(productBarcode)

        // Remove the item from Firebase
        itemRef.removeValue()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                // Successfully removed from Firebase
                items.removeAt(position) // Remove the item from the list in memory

                // Notify the adapter that the item was removed
                notifyItemRemoved(position)

                // If the list is empty, show a message or handle UI changes accordingly
                if (items.isEmpty()) {
                    // Optionally, hide the RecyclerView or show an empty view
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No items left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // If needed, set RecyclerView visibility to GONE or update the UI accordingly
                    // recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    // Update the remaining items in the list
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                // Handle error if the removal failed
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to remove item: ${exception.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
    }



    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
}


and my ProductData.kt
package com.example.negeshoca

data class ProductData(
    val productBarcode: String = "",
    val productName: String = "",
    val productPrice: Double = 0.0,
    val qty : Int = 1

)



it works fine but there's a catch in what's happening. It's that when there's a few items(let's say 3 items in the recyclerview on my scenario), when i remove the first item in the list, it's data will also be removed from firebase under "/scannedItems" but the second item will also be removed along with the first item from the recyclerview(but the second item's data will remain in the firebase). The last item remains in the recyclerview. Next is when the second item is removed, it happens the same with last item. Lastly, is whenever im removing the last item in the recyclerview, it closes the app.
